# Vuejs - property 'id' of undefined when using router.push()

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, antdv

Hi so I have a table where all my info is registered and one field has a button to consult each row . what I want is getting the id of each row and pass it in the router.push but doing so get's me the undefined error can anyone help me how to make this work?

I use Ant Design Vue that's why I have a- elements,here's my file

```
<a-table :data-source="dataSource" :columns="columns" :loading="loading" rowKey="id">
// ive got more code here but this is the button code  :
<template #details>
    <span>
      <a-button
        @click="click(record)"
        class="btn btn-sm btn-light mr-2"
      >
        Details
      </a-button>
    </span>
  </template>
</a-table>
     <script>
      setup()      
 {const router = useRouter()
    const click = (record) => {
      router.push({ 
          name:'details' , params:{id:[record.id]},
        })
    }
   }
```

How can I really get the id to successfully pass it and open my new page?

Comment: Where is the `record` object defined?

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with Ant Design. Did a Google search, and have you tried adding a slot-scope to your template? So `<template #Details slot-scope="text, record">`

Comment: thank u ,  I did indeed need to add that record in my template , what I used actually is `<template #Details="{record}">` and it worked . I have another issue that is related to the new page but i'll let this one to help others if they get same issue so can u please check this one out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67634101/vuejs-second-axios-get-not-reached-in-if-else-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i missed a simple details and thanks to Matt U i get it :
i just have to add "record" in my template this way :

```
  <template #details="{record}"> <-- here's the add
    <span>
      <a-button
        @click="click(record)"
        class="btn btn-sm btn-light mr-2"
      >
        Details
      </a-button>
    </span>
  </template>
```