# Vuejs- Second axios.get not reached in if..else statement

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3

So I have this vue where it gets id and user_type from another vue . I have two user types : fr and en both have their own get request to get the right data . this is how I passed them down :

```
  const click = (record) => {
      router.push({ 
          name:'details' , params:{id:record.id,user_type:record.user_type},
        })
    }
```

Now in my  file of my new vue named 'details' I do this :

```
     let id =route.params.id
    let user_type=route.params.user_type
onMounted(async () => {
  if(user_type="fr")
 {
    await axios
    .get('/lang/DetailFR/'+id)
    .then((res) => {
      dataSource.value = res.data
      console.log( "here",dataSource.value )
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
 } 
  else if (user_type="en") {
    await axios
    .get('/lang/DetailFEN/'+id)
    .then((res) => {
      dataSource.value = res.data
      console.log( "where",dataSource.value )
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  }
 
   
})
```

SO when it's user_type=fr it works fine I get the data in console with the "here" msg but if my user_type is =en what I get in console is "here" and not "where" and no data desplayed obviously so the "if else " is not working and I don't know why.
PS: if I only use user_type=en I get the right request to work and the "what" msg shown so problem is   with the if..else or something.
Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user_type==="fr"` instead of `user_type="fr"`

Comment: the user_type="fr" works fine it's when my user type is en , where it should run the else if section it doesn't , it runs the if statement .

Comment: i hope this is not your actual code. `user_type="fr"` is not a comparison expression but an assignment

Comment: yeaah that's true but it's weird cuz it works with `user_type="fr"` but whit === it doesn't ...

Comment: then you need to check what is the real value of user_type. the reason `if (user_type="fr")` works is because assignment in js will return the assigned value, hence you are effectively doing `if ("fr")` . non-empty string in js is considered true

Comment: well u're right it's undefined i just console log it , xhat should i do now?

Comment: I fixed it I was passing the user_type the wrong way and then I used `user_type==="fr"` it works fine thank u

Comment: check why it is undefined? where is the value supposed to be provided? is the value there? `user_type:[record.id].user_type` why there is a `[ ]` ?

Comment: i fixed it yeah i was just suppoded to do user_type:record.user_type